# Tool or framework for Linux device driver testing?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, ethernet, i2c

I want to test the compliance of Linux Ethernet and I2C drivers. Is there any open source tool or framework to test these drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Compliance with what? Usually, the organization which publishes the standards with which you want to be compliant also publish the corresponding testsuites, or at least can tell you where to get them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to identify suitable testsuite/framework/tool from organization that publishes the standard, you can always fall back to LTP (Linux Test Project).

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Test_Project)

[another guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2002/ols2002-pages-265-273.pdf)

This framework tests complete functionality of system calls and many other libraries found in any Linux distribution. It performs thousands of tests. Only smaller portion will be relevant to your drivers, bur there will be some. With the right hardware and software setup you will be fine.